# Memtest86 showed errors with my RAM... what next?

Tags: memory, bsod, memtest

I've been experiencing BSOD's for years now, and they've recently gotten worse. I'm fed up with them and decided to get rid of them once and for all. I often get messages regarding/mentioning memory, so logically I thought that would be the first step.

I ran [Memtest86](http://memtest.org/) and it came up with 18 errors. Any ideas as to what I do now? Logically it would seem the BSOD's are being caused by faulty RAM.

My specs are as follows:

- OS: Windows 10 Insider Preview
- CPU: AMD FX-6300
- RAM: 8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 671MHz (9-9-9-24)
- Motherboard: GA-990FXA-UD3
- GPU:  2047MB GTX 770

Also worth noting my hard drive failed last summer and had to get a new one. That may or may not be related.

Comment: It would be useful to know the BSOD error code, which starts with 0x. In case of bad memory you should replace it with new - it can't be repaired.

Comment: Try this flavor of Memtest, see if you get same results....http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: DDR3 @ 671Mhz?? That's really slow. That's DDR2 speed. What brand is your RAM?

Comment: @Moab used that one, my bad. Forgot to add the +

Comment: @Alexiy I'll make sure to write it down. Some of the errors I remember offhand are MEMORY_MANAGEMENT and IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. I'll try to remember to get the error codes next time I get one (which will probably be tomorrow).

Comment: @AndroidDev Not sure. http://prntscr.com/alewp5 That's all the information I have offhand. How could I find the brand for you?

Comment: @index.php your link is to the other one?

Comment: @Moab what do you mean?

Comment: The link in your question is different software than the one I linked to.

Comment: @Moab my bad, updated that. The one in there now is the one I used.

Comment: CPU-Z will get you the brand.

Answer (score 0):

As you have equipment capable of overclocking, the first step you'll want to take is to disable overclocking on the RAM/FSB.  Lowering the CPU overclock may also resolve problems.  This may solve the BSOD and RAM errors, if the RAM is unstable at the frequency you have it running.  671MHz is comparatively low speed, but you did not mention the brand/model of RAM you are using.  If you still experience issues, you will want to remove one stick (presuming you use two sticks of that freq. RAM to achieve 8 GB) and run memtest again.  If it fails, swap the RAM modules and retest.  It is likely that one but less likely that both modules are faulty.

The repair method in this case is replacement, it is more cost effective to purchase a new stick (or preferably a new pair of matching sticks) than to diagnose and replace the faulty chip/s on a defective stick of RAM.

Remember to install matching RAM pairs in the 2nd and 4th slot away from your CPU on that motherboard (DDR3_1 and DDR3_2).  This can be verified from the owners manual, linked below:
"For optimum performance, when enabling Dual Channel mode with two memory modules, we recommend that you install them in the DDR3_1 and DDR3_2 sockets."

http://www.gigabyte.fi/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3894#manual

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though I consider myself to be good with computers, I'll get my friend who knows a lot more about hardware to help me out with that. I'll pay attention to a few more answers/comments on here for a while, but otherwise  I'll probably go through with getting a new stick or two. It's old RAM anyway, so I might just get new RAM altogether.

Comment: Happy to help, don't forget to up-vote a good answer :)

Comment: I slightly disagree--you should test with the minimum possible number of sticks installed.  Finding the bad one is faster this way.

Comment: In no way is that disagreeing with what I have written.  2-1=1, the minimum operable number of RAM modules.

Answer (score -2):

Can you give us the underlying issue?
We could use the DMP files and event viewer logs

We do need the actual log files (called a DMP files) as they contain the only record of the sequence of events leading up to the crash, what drivers were loaded, and what was responsible.

Please follow our instructions for finding and uploading the files we need to help you fix your computer. They can be found here
If you have any questions about the procedure please ask

Please read this wiki to find out how to find and upload your event viewer logs

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question asked.